# Drupal - Mandatory CCK date and time field - Only date is mandatory

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a CCK field of date and time. The widget type is 'Text Field with Date Pop-up calendar'. The field is mandatory.

The date works fine, but if you leave the time blank (hours and minutes), the node can be created and the time field reads '(All day)'. How can I make it mandatory to specify a time in hours and minutes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using datestamp instead of datetime:

"[datestamp] must be filled with a complete date -- year, month, day, hour, minute, second, so you sometimes have to arbitrarily set some of these values even if they are not applicable."

http://drupal.org/node/262066

Answer (score 0):

In the date settings you have granularity, I think selecting hours and minutes there might solve your problem.